# Signal command map injection error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, robotlegs

I am using Robotlegs to create a simple application in as3, which I have been using for a couple of months now. I seem to be getting an injection error when injecting the ISignalCommandMap into my config file, which has only started happening after I moved my application from one computer to another. It may be to do with conflicting libraries, but I have re-downloaded the newest versions of everything. I am also using starling in the application, but everything was working on the other computer.

Here is the error I am getting
 Injector is missing a mapping to handle injection into property "commandMap" of object "[object Config]" with type "Config::Config". Target dependency: "robotlegs.bender.extensions.signalCommandMap.api::ISignalCommandMap|"

Any thoughts to why this has started happening?

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was extending MVCSBundle like in [this example project](https://github.com/katopz/robotlegs2-SignalCommandMap-example/blob/master/src/modules/moduleone/config/ModuleOneBundle.as) and then using that class in place of MVCSBundle.